# Explain difference in riwayat Warsh

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, qiraat

I was looking at different reading of Al-Quran by Warsh on website [Quranflash](https://app.quranflash.com/), Website provide to two kind of Warsh (Warsh - Asbahani way and Warsh - King Fahd Complex), as I was working on Wasl reading practices I want see other reading also,I find something which I don't known. please Explain the Following :-Frist, Different style of writing Wasl (solid dot over alif with fataha) please Explain that. Second and more Important(in 23:14) is spelling of khalaqa, why single dot? [spelling](https://app.quranflash.com/book/Warsh1?en#/reader) [image]

and it's different from this [Warsh](https://app.quranflash.com/book/Warsh2?en#/reader/chapter/344) by some-website [image]

But this different is not seen in [nquran.com](https://www.nquran.com/ar/ayacompare/%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA?sora=23&aya=14)

Answer (score 1):

**Warsh's students or turuq**

First of all you should know that imam Warsh had at least two known students al-Asbahani to whom he had mainly taught one reading path from which imam Nafi'i taught him and al-Azraq which he taught the reading which is practiced and well known in the countries of north Africa.

**A simplified definition of terms: qira'a (reading), riwaya (version of the reading) and tariq (path of the riwaya)**

In other words you may find for each qir'a'a a riwaya (a version of the reading of the imam to whom it refer's) and a tariq (a path through which the riwaya was transmitted even through some of the books of qira'at).
Therefore experts make a difference between the 10 qira'at al-Kubra ("big") and the the 10 qira'at as-Sughra ("small") based on the path of transmission. As at the end any of these paths starts with one of the 10 imams.
Basically there's already a difference between two riwayaat (plural of riwaya/version) from one imam. Nevertheless sometimes even the turuq (plural of tariq/path) have some specific differences, but for that these turuq must be known and practiced (I only know of the turuq of Warsh and Qalun 'an Nafi'i being practiced).
The differences may apply on both the so called osol (the generally applied basic rules) and the farsh (the specific performance of some words) so the difference might be in the language spelling or even grammar (plural/singular, passive/active voice for example) or on the tajweed rules.
One could say that the huge amount of differences between the two riwayat of 'Assim (Hafs and Sho'abah -also known as abu Bakr ibn 'Ayyash) > 500 is rather a singularity in this context.

**On your example verses**

As for the differences between Warsh 'an Nafi'i bi tariq al-Azraq and bi tariq al-Asbahani, only experts know some differences:
From what I see here I expect a difference in the recitation of:
[image]
where the hamza in the middle is pronounced (al-Azraq).
And
[image]
where the hamza is not pronounced -apparently- and only the "alif" is pronounced (al-Asbahani).

Else I couldn't make out any difference here because the upper picture is written in a style close to the typical north African style of the Warsh Moshafs, which is close to Kufi style while the lower picture shows a modern Arabic writing style.

In other words:
the letter written with a dot on top:

> ـفـ

in the upper picture simply is a:

> ـقـ
> qaf

you may have noticed that the letter

> faa'
> ـفـ

looks like a faa' with one dot below the letter in the mid of a word at the end it could even appear without any dot (See also in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Arabic_script&oldid=1080401735)).

See also:
[How many writing styles of Mushaf Quran that exist?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37679/how-many-writing-styles-of-mushaf-quran-that-exist)
[Quran originally without vowel marks?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38179/quran-originally-without-vowel-marks)

As for how to write hamzat al-Wasl this is the rasm choice which was reported from Warsh and therefore the choice for Moshafs of Warsh. As a matter of fact the position of the dot indicates how the alif should be pronounced.

Comment: Can you provide link regarding different writing style of Arabic?

Comment: @PolarStar it is a question of writing style of Moshafs see for example [What are the different punctuation in Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/37594/13438) and the links I've hared already.