# What is the sign on Alif (The filled black dot on Alif and the mark ( like Fattah/Kasra )below and above Alif. )? How to read it?

Tags: quran, tajweed

What is the sign on Alif? How to read it?[image]

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you're asking about the filled black dot above the Alif in the highlighted letters?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the filled black dot on Alif and the mark ( like Fattah/Kasra )below and above Alif.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain difference in riwayat Warsh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75474/explain-difference-in-riwayat-warsh)

Comment: @umH, Jazakumullah Khair.. The answer (you suggested) did not convey the full answer what I asked to know

Comment: seems like it is a font issue for me.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the qur"an copy you are referring to (riwaya, edition...)? My first guess is that these symbols emphasize the difference between al-shamsiya and al-qamariya in Arabic grammar.

Answer (score 0):

See, the different *riwayaat* of Quran recitation may have different connotations meant by that filled dot.
I will speak from my experience with the *Riwayaat Hafs 'an 'Asim*.
The filled dot, like in Surah Fussilat, means that you can pronounce the dot in two ways: either as a normal hamza or a very subtle, breathy ha. Like, in Surah Fussilat, the word ءَا۬عْجَمِىٌّۭ, you can pronounce it as either a-aa'jamiyyun or a-ha'jamiyyun.