# Question about a Word in Quran

Tags: quran

In my Quran there is written for the word Torah this word:
تورية

Is it wrong? Because there is a ya, but in the word Taurat there is no ya.

Comment: This is covered in [Why do words like Salah and riba have an extra in pronounced letter was in the moshaf](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1666/why-do-words-like-salah-and-riba-have-an-extra-unpronounced-letter-waw-in-th#30994), however without showing the corresponding verse and page of the Moshaf it is a vague question. Note that the Qur'an is the orally transmitted word of Allah, what you hold in hands is a Moshaf

Answer (score 1):

The ya that you are referring to is Alif Maksoorah. It is pronounced like an Alif. It is usually found without the two dots like this. ٱلتَّوْرَىٰةِ

In your case the ya is written incorrectly. It is not supposed to have two dots.  The ya that has been used in your case is Ya-Al-mutatarrifa which usually comes in the end like في

I personally stick to uthmani script because of the following verdict.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/98922/writing-quraan-on-mobile-phones-in-something-other-than-the-uthmaani-script

This explanation also might be useful.

[You'll NEVER mis-pronounce ى in the Quran after watching this](https://youtu.be/nk3wjTBluSo)